# Best way to detect and store path combinations for analysing purpose later

Tags: path, storage, design-patterns, pattern-recognition

I am searching for ideas/examples on how to store path patterns from users - with the goal of analysing their behaviours and optimizing on "most used path" when we can detect them somehow.

Eg. which action do they do after what, so that we later on can check to see if certain actions are done over and over again - therefore developing a shortcut or assembling some of the actions into a combined multiaction.

My first guess would be some sort of "simple log", perhaps stored in some SQL-manner, where we can keep each action as an index and then just record everything.

Problem is that the path/action might be dynamically changed - even while logging - so we need to be able to take care of this fact too, when looking for patterns later.

Would you log everthing "bigtime" first and then POST-process every bit of details after some time or do you have great experience with other tactics?

My worry is that this is going to take up space, BIG TIME while logging 1000 users each day for a month or more.

Hope this makes sense and I am curious to see if anyone can provide sample code, pseudocode or perhaps links to something usefull.

Our tools will be C#, SQL-database, XML and .NET 3.5 - clients could also get .NET 4.0 if needed.

**Patterns examples as we expect them**

```
...
User #1001: A-B-A-A-A-B-C-E-F-G-H-A-A-A-C-B-A
User #1002: B-A-A-B-C-E-F
User #1003: F-B-B-A-E-C-A-A-A   
User #1002: C-E-F
...
```

etc. no real way to know what they do next nor how many they will use, how often they will do it.

A secondary goal, if possible, if we later on add a new "action" called G (just sample to illustrate, there will be hundreds of actions) how could we detect these new behaviours influence on the previous patterns.

To explain it better, my thought here would be some way to detect "patterns within patterns", sort of like how compressions work, so that "repeative patterns" are spottet. We dont know how long these patterns might be, nor how often they might come. How do we break this down into "small bits and pieces" - whats the best approach you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pseudo idea/implementation so far**

1. Log ever users action into a list/series of actions, bulk kinda style (textfiles/SQL - what ever, just store the whole thing for post-processing)
2. start counting every "1 action", "2 actions", "3 actions" up til a certain amount (lets say 30 levels)
3. sort them all, by giving values of importants to some of the actions (might be those producing end results)

**A usefull result perhaps?**

If we count all [A], [A-A], [A-B], [A-C], [A-A-A], [A-A-B] etc. its going to make a LONG and fine list of which actions are used in row frequently, and thats in the right direction, because if some of these results gets too high, we might need a shorter path. Problem is then, whats too few actions to be optimized and whats the longest needed actionlist to search for? My guess is that we need to do this counting first, then examine the numbers.

Problem is that this would be part of an analyzing tool we are developing and we dont have data until implementation, so we dont know what to look for before its actually done. hmm... wondering if there really IS an answer to this one.

Comment: closing my question. Dont know how if I dont just "mark it answered".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by path, but, if you gave every action in a path a unique symbol, you could reduce the problem to longest common substring or subsequence.

Or have a map of paths to the number of times that action occurred. Every time a certain path happens, increment the count for that path. Then sort to find the most common.

Comment: interesting, I will try to explain it a bit better in the question.